# Trouble with webscraping to clean CSV tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** some data from a table. I got the results that I expect but I can not find the way to save them in a clean CSV table. This is the code, below the result and what I want. Any advice?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request # web access
import csv
import re

url = "https://wsc.nmbe.ch/family/87/Senoculidae"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # conntect to website
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
    print("Ups!")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

regex = re.compile('^speciesTitle')
content_lis = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': regex})

for li in content_lis:
    con = li.get_text("#",strip=True).split("\n")[0]
    print(con)
```

I got these nice output:

```
Senoculus albidus#(F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1897)#|#| Brazil
Senoculus barroanus#Chickering, 1941#|#| Panama
Senoculus bucolicus#Chickering, 1941#|#| Panama
```

But I need something like this (CSV separated by semicolon or tab):

```
Senoculus albidus;(F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1897);Brazil
Senoculus barroanus;Chickering1941;Panama
Senoculus bucolicus;Chickering, 1941;Panama
```

How do I remove the character "|" and some spaces? Any advice?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

This code works based on your sample dataset:

```
lst=[
'Senoculus albidus#(F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1897)#|#| Brazil',
'Senoculus barroanus#Chickering, 1941#|#| Panama',
'Senoculus bucolicus#Chickering, 1941#|#| Panama'
]

lst2 = [s.replace('|',"").split('#') for s in lst]

lst3=[]

for s in lst2:
   lst3.append(';'.join([sx.strip() for sx in s]).replace(';;',';'))

for s in lst3:
   print(s)
```

Output

```
Senoculus albidus;(F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1897);Brazil 
Senoculus barroanus;Chickering, 1941;Panama 
Senoculus bucolicus;Chickering, 1941;Panama
```

--- Update based on requester comment ---

Add an additional line to your final loop:

```
for li in content_lis:
    con = li.get_text("#",strip=True).split("\n")[0]
    con = ';'.join(sx.strip() for sx in con.replace('|',"").split('#')).replace(';;',';') # add this line
    print(con)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!, there is a way that this step came after the "con" object (string)?. There are 128 pages with the same structure but the output it is a long list of items (string class) as the output I showed.

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I took a look at it it seems to me that it might be better to find the path for each piece of info you want because it's picking up other things you might not want. I edited to comma-separated it and remove the bars but still small issues.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request # web access
import csv
import re

url = "https://wsc.nmbe.ch/family/87/Senoculidae"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # conntect to website
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
    print("Ups!")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#regex = re.compile('^speciesTitle')

for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': "speciesTitle"}):
    con = div.get_text(',',strip=True).split("\n")[0].replace('|,|','')
    print(con)
```

Comment: Well, this method was the most helpful for my question, I just add more characters to replace.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request # web access
import re

url = "https://wsc.nmbe.ch/family/87/Senoculidae"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # conntect to website
try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except:
    print("Ups!")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
#div = soup.find(text=True, recursive=)
regex = re.compile('^speciesTitle')
content_lis = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': regex})
file = ''
for cl in content_lis:
    a = cl.select_one('div a strong i')
    b = cl.find(text=True, recursive=False)
    c = cl.select_one('span')
    cc = re.findall("[\w]+", c.text)[0]
    file += f'{a.get_text(strip=True)};{b.strip()};{cc}\n'
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
   f.write(file)
```

saves a file with:

```
Senoculus albidus;(F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1897);Brazil
Senoculus barroanus;Chickering, 1941;Panama
Senoculus bucolicus;Chickering, 1941;Panama
Senoculus cambridgei;Mello-Leitão, 1927;Brazil
Senoculus canaliculatus;F. O. Pickard-Cambridge, 1902;Mexico
Senoculus carminatus;Mello-Leitão, 1927;Brazil
Senoculus darwini;(Holmberg, 1883);Argentina
Senoculus fimbriatus;Mello-Leitão, 1927;Brazil
Senoculus gracilis;(Keyserling, 1879);Guyana
Senoculus guianensis;Caporiacco, 1947;j
Senoculus iricolor;(Simon, 1880);Brazil
Senoculus maronicus;Taczanowski, 1872;French
```

and so on...